# Fit exponential curve through data points in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Having data of an exponential decay available, I would like to fit a curve through it. How can I do that in Matlab?

Comment: There is a nice demo on the Statistics Toolbox product page that discusses problems that can occur if you transform a nonlinear model to a linear one.                                                                                          http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/xform2lineardemo.html                                                                               The preferred method is to use nonlinear regression; deriving a set a "smart" starting conditions using the "linearize, least squares, delinearize" technique.

Comment: The comment by Richard Willey should really be the (accepted) answer. Linearizing and applying least squares as recommended in some of the answers is not a good idea since the transformation will give too much weight to small values. Better use nlinfit.

Comment: Link from @richardwilley has been broken by The MathWorks. Updated version appears to be [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/curve-fitting-and-distribution-fitting.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ft=fittype('exp1');
cf=fit(time,data,ft)
```

This is when `time` and `data` are your data vectors; time is the independent variable and data is the dependent variable.

This will give you the coefficients of the exponential decay curve.

Comment: how would one plot this?

Comment: @Adiel When i tried this I get an error as `Undefined function 'diff' for input arguments of type
'cfit'.

Error in cfit/plot (line 64)
   if any(diff(xdata)<0)

Error in slopeFirst2hours (line 6)
plot(time, cf, 'r')
 ` Can you tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: @clarkson You are right. It should be plotted with a single command- `plot(cf,time,data)`

Answer (score 2):

If by fit you mean least squares, you should try lsqcurvefit

Answer (score 1):

cftool(X,Y) is the way to go.
here's some linkage:

[LINK1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/cftool.html)
[LINK2](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/MatlabCurveFit/MatlabCftool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a function called polyfit. It can fit curve to a data which can be represented in the form a*X^n+b*X^(n-1)+.....z. However if you are sure that the data is of some exponential decay you can try taking logarithm of the data first and then using the polyfit function. I thing that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Linearise, least squares, delinearise :-)

Comment: You are right, although I thought there might be a package that does that for me automatically it is probably less time consuming to just do it manually rather than searching for it :)

Comment: This is pretty short for an answer, but I upvoted it from -1 because it is helpful for users without the Curve Fitting toolbox.